# Facebook like button callback with javascript alert box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, callback

I would like an alert box to be displayed after the user has successfully clicked the Facebook Like button. I'm having trouble getting the following code working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.Event.subscribe(edge.create, function() {
   alert('You just liked the page!');
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

edge.create has to be in quotes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
   alert('You just liked the page!');
 });
</script>
```